# Using widgets on Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having issues with running my widgets on my Django forms. Below is the block of code. Prior to this, I had already installed the necessary Bootstrap element to my base.html file. Please help. Thank you.

```
from django import forms
```

from .models import Post

```
class PostForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Post
        fields= ('title', 'title_tag', 'author', 'body')

widgets= {
    'title': forms.TextInput (attrs= {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter title here'}),
    'title': forms.TextInput (attrs= {'class': 'form-control'}),
    'author': forms.Select (attrs= {'class': 'form-control'}),
    'body': forms.Textarea (attrs= {'class': 'form-control'}),
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is the indentation of `widgets` exactly as you show in the question? It is supposed to be inside the class `Meta`.

Comment: @funnydman I'm not really getting any error. It's just not working.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Your suggestion worked. Thank you very much.